# Как оптимизировать код C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, оптимизация

Надо оптимизировать код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int a;
  cin >> a;
  int *a1 = new int[a];
  int *a2 = new int[a];
  int *a3 = new int[a];
  for(int i = 0; i<a; i++){
      cin >> a1[i];
  }
  int x = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i<a; i++){
      cin >> a2[i];
  }
  for(int i = 0; i<a; i++){
      cin >> a3[i];
  }
  for(int i =0; i<a; i++){
      for(int b = 0; b < a; b++){
        for(int n = 0; n< a; n++){
            if(a1[i]<a2[b]&&a2[b]<a3[n]){
          x++;
          }
            }
      } }
  cout << x;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, пишите более подробные вопросы. Что именно вы хотите оптимизировать, непонятно. Толи скорость кода не устраивает, толи количество строк хочется сократить, толи ещё что. Мы должны гадать?

Comment: избавиться от трёх циклов друг в друге

Comment: скорость кода не устраивает

Comment: Похоже от третьего цикла тут не избавится.

Comment: это университетское задание?

Comment: нет, задание из олимпиады

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите что бы мы вам решили олимпиаду - а победа за вами - круто:)

Comment: это прошлогодняя, хочу подготовиться

Comment: Тут неправильно логика выстроена (избыточная нагрузка). Почитайте условие (которое вы поленились написать) и перестройте.

Comment: нужно найти количество вариантов a1<a2<a3, 3 цикла for очень медлят работу

Answer (score 1):

Можно же вынести первое сравнение из третьего цикла:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (a1[i] < a2[j])
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
            {
                if (a2[j] < a3[k])
                    x++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если не знаете, что делать - отсортируйте данные (© мудрость старых алгоритмистов)

Пусть даны три массива `A[], B[], C[]`
Отсортировали всё.
Завели вспомогательный массив `D[]`, тоже с длиной `N`

Встали на первый элемент **второго** массива (`ib=0`).
Нашли индекс первого большего элемента **третьего** массива такой, что `С[iс] > B[0]`.
Записали в `D[0]` значение `N - ic` - это количество таких пар, что `C[j]>B[0]`
Продвинули индекс в массиве `B[]` вправо, повторили. И так до конца.
Получили, к примеру, массив `D = [7, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, где `D[1]=4` означает, что существует 4 "хороших" пары c элементом `B[1]`

Теперь пройдём массив `D[]` с **конца**, записывая в него кумулятивные суммы, накопленные с конца же. `[7, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] = > [13, 6, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`
Здесь `D[1]=6` означает, что существует 6 "хороших" пар для элементов `B[]` с индексами, начинающимися с 1 и правее (`B[1], B[2]` и т.д.)

Встали на первый элемент **первого** массива (`ia=0`).
Нашли индекс первого большего элемента **второго** массива такой, что `B[ib] > A[0]`.
Добавили значение `D[ib]` к результату.
Одним махом посчитали целую кучу троек!

Продвигаем индекс `ia` в первом массиве вправо, повторяем до конца.

Первый этап `O(NlogN)`, остальные линейные `O(N)`, т.к. индексы всегда движутся только в одну сторону